# How to specify the selectors for a nodeport service through the command line?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
Create a new service to access the web application using the service-definition-1.yaml file

```yaml
  Name: webapp-service
  Type: NodePort
  targetPort: 8080
  port: 8080
  nodePort: 30080
  selector: simple-webapp
```

I ran the command

```sh
kubectl create service nodeport webapp-service --tcp=8080:8080 --node-port=30080
```

and got everything I wanted. However, I have to manually create & edit the  yaml file to add the selector: `simple-webapp`.

I was curious if I could specify the selectors for a service through the command line?

Comment: You can also consider using [`kubectl expose`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose) but it doesn't have a possibility to provide a `nodeport` number, only random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
kubectl create service nodeport webapp-service --tcp 8080:8080 --node-port 30080 \ 
    --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl set selector --local -f - app=simple-webapp -o yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you are looking for is "Labels and Selectors"

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

```
kubectl get pods -l environment=production,tier=frontend
```